# How does Sitecore EXM track the Email Opens Rate?

Tags: exm

I am using EXM Version 9.0.1, with Sitecore 9 update 1 installation.

I have created the campaign and want to track the email open rate in the report section, but my Email open rates are not capturing , as I am using the simple html template/Plain text Message Template and email body is not clickable.

So I wondering,  there is no action happened on the email body and sitecore is not able to track any action of "email Open"

However, If I select the other template, which has some action on the html body and in that case my "email opens" tracks properly as its passing some query string to the Sitecore Site.

Am I missing any configuration to "explicitly track the email open rate" or what is the logic behind the tracking open rate ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The question is: How does EXM track opens?

During dispatch, EXM automatically embeds a tracking pixel to the bottom of the rendered email. The tracking pixels link's to *RegisterEmailOpened.ashx* on the Content Delivery server.

The RegisterOpen process logs the open event as an Interaction on the Contact in xConnect/xDB.

1. The first step to troubleshooting this process is examining the raw content of a sent piece of mail and looking for the tracking pixel. The tracking pixel is an `<img>` tag that is present on the bottom of a sent piece of mail. If you don't see that, the email layout you're using isn't correctly adding the pixel. (All of the OOTB templates put this).  This does NOT exist when you run a "Email Test" from EXM.

   ```
       <body style=3D"margin:4px;" >
           <p>
               <strong>This is an example email</strong>
           </p>
           <p>
               <strong>&nbsp;</strong>
           </p>
           <p>Sending this to Test User 12 Tester.</p>
           <p>&nbsp;</p>
           <p>Thanks,</p>
           <p>&nbsp;</p>
           <p>Pete</p>
           <img height=3D"1" width=3D"1" border=3D"0" style=3D"border-color: transparent;" src=3D"https://www.exampledomain.net//sitecore%20modules/Web/EXM/RegisterEmailOpened.ashx?ec_eq=3DH5aEpKOBu%2fmLhjhgLykgb8K2TUlbxiVIldiWwGN%2bFjKr6M%2byrSbBj%2fB7vYTiU9gFHULILVZO%2fPh8aDWOx9spG58v0lcdrY1NH%2b40hYZW5SV1p8uTCOjb5NDd%2fqLqnxoEBRHfyV5WLJW%2f%2bJruq1kIhAlmo5mQUuKqgARg938jAZpY6oKsryxGumMlNoDfwHMGdLPoTcsNeVy22kJ0%2fcvUDZBchsq4GlnFLRWWbaZ4419KB5ue2zlho9AJQ1d2vNFg" alt=3D"" />
       </body>
   ```
2. Also, look at the Manager Root item and make sure that "Track Message Open" is checked on the Manager Root. 
   [image]
3. Next is to make sure that the pixel is loading correctly. Take the URL, and all of the query string parameters from the raw output of a dispatched piece of mail, and try to run it.  Verify that you don't get any 404 or 500 errors.  If it works, it will just be blank.
4. If that seems to work, verify all logs (Sitecore and xConnect) that communication is working.  At this point, if it still isn't working, you will be troubleshooting your xDB implementation which is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Pete Thanks for the information but I am Unable to find the Pixel information with link to RegisterOpen.aspx, is it something EXM dynamically add at the time of sending email? can you please help me to find that information, So I can manually Add that Information. 2nd Point is - is it required  to click on the email body in order to track the  email open rate? for example- if I just open the email, and not do any-action on the email, will it track as "open email"

Comment: @AshishBansal I've edited the answer to answer part of your question. You're not required to click anything in the email body, just open the email. You may have to allow your email client to download pictures though.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, Now its all clear to me, I can see the handler named "RegisterEmailOpened.ashx" in the HTML of the email

Comment: Ashish, posted some more detail, sorry about the delay in getting that completely updated.   @JacobNielsen thanks for the editing help.  There was only so much I could recall from memory when I typed the original answer out on my phone.